# How to get nextval of dynamic sequence

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have tried to optimize my code and use a shared method for the cases where I need to get sequence nextval for multiple sequences in my application.
But when I tried to do it as clean and safe as possible it is not working.

Working but not safe :

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT " + seqName + ".NEXTVAL FROM DUAL");
```

Safe but not working :

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT :SEQ_NAME.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL");
q.setParameter("SEQ_NAME", seqName);
```

Do you know how to write this better ? Thanks.

Comment: Bind variables can only be used to provide object values, not names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Oracle, you have to reference the sequence as a literal name. What makes your current version unsafe is the possibility to inject SQL in the sequence name. Couldn't you add a verification in the method that the sequence name contains only letters, numbers, dots and perhaps underscores, and the current could would actually be safe...?

```
if(!seqName.matches("[A-Za-z._]+"))
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid sequence name: " + seqName);
```

Comment: That's fine until someone works out how to [bypass your function to sanitise the user input](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/252475/261465) and then you still have an SQL injection problem.

Comment: Well, that's why the sanity check should be rather restrictive, and explicitly tell what characters to allow...

Comment: I will accept this as right answer because it speaks more closely to my quality topic. But also @MT0 answer was valid and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic SQL within Oracle and then use `DBMS_ASSERT` to validate that the bind variable is an SQL Object:

```sql
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'SELECT ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME(:seqname) || '.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL'
    INTO :value;
END;
```

And then call that from Java with an IN (`seqname`) and an OUT (`value`) bind parameter.

---

However, you probably don't want to do that.

> I have tried to optimize my code and use a shared method for the cases where I need to get sequence nextval for multiple sequences in my application.

This appears to be taking the DRY principles too far and you are starting to compromise security and making things too complicated.

Just use the name of the sequence in the DML statements when you need to:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (id, col1, col2)
VALUES (table_name__seq.NEXTVAL, 'value1', 'value2')
```

If you need to get the sequence value following an `INSERT` then use:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (id, col1, col2)
VALUES (table_name__seq.NEXTVAL, 'value1', 'value2')
RETURNING id INTO :bind_variable
```

and then you can use that value to add children that reference that parent's generated primary key value.

Or, from Oracle 12, skip manually managing the sequence and use an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. In most cases we use identity but these few cases we need the id value prior to commit.

Comment: @cosmincalistru Then use an identity sequence and combine it with `INSERT ... RETURNING id INTO :bind_variable` to get the value when you insert it.